# Moving cancel and confirm button to down using Ionic ion-picker

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic6

I am new to ionic. I have a requirement to change the cancel and confirm button to bottom of the picker like below.

Expected Result

[image]

I am using Angular with ionic.
The options i have given is like below

```
buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
           console.log(');
        },
        {
          text: 'Select',
          role: 'heading',
          cssClass: 'pickerHeading',
        },
        {
          text: 'confirm',
          handler: (columns: any) => {
            console.log('')
          },
          role: 'submit',
        },
      ],
      columns: [
        
           {
              text: 'Female',
              value: 'female',
            },
            {
              text: 'Male',
              value: 'male',
            }
      ],
```

Can anyone help here

Comment: Does your screenshot show the expected result or the current one? What exactly are you trying to change? Can you at least provide some code one can work with?

Comment: I need the only the cancel and confirm button to the bottom of the page. @FabianStrathaus

Comment: What did you try so far and what was the result? From your screenshot it looks like the buttons are already at the bottom of the page.

Comment: The screenshot attached is what i expected. currently the buttons are at the top

Comment: create your own component and give it custom css and make it as u like... but as deafult ionic components they are kinda fixed all the same